# ASP.NET Core Web Api authorization for specific web apps (instead of users)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token

I'm building an ASP.NET Core web service that I would only like a few specific applications to access. I know Web Api's typically use Bearer Tokens for authentication. But the examples I see all send a username and password.

Is the same method of token authentication typically used for authorizing specific applications?
But instead, the application sends its client ID and password instead of username and password?

Comment: Take a look at http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/ .  See the clients table? You'd probably want to do something like that, if... your applications has users, so a client has mutiple users identified by the client_id that then login from that client.  If your use case is simpler, then an application should equal a user and should just login as such I believe.